# inline javascript are interrupting the load of the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I want the html are fully loaded then execute the inline javascript because this script stops the load of the html document.

To try to solve this problem I put the inline javascript code at the end inside a div then i use the jquery  .append method

$("#subhimedia").appendTo("#himedia");

This works and appends the inline js that is located inside #subhimedia and takes it inside the #himedia div.

The probblem is that duplicate the #subhimedia div and in internet explorer it freeze the browser.

The inline javascript is:

```
<!--JavaScript Tag // Tag for network 258: Hi-Media Portugal // Website: Lifecooler // Page: HOME // Placement: HOME_MREC_300x250 (1653713) // created at: Aug 29, 2008 1:35:27 PM-->
                <script language="javascript"><!--
                document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="javascript1.1" src="http://adserver.adtech.de/addyn|3.0|258|1653713|0|170|ADTECH;loc=100;target=_blank;grp=[group];misc='+new Date().getTime()+'"></scri'+'pt>');
    //-->
                </script><noscript><a href="http://adserver.adtech.de/adlink|3.0|258|1653713|0|170|ADTECH;loc=300;grp=[group]" target="_blank"><img src="http://adserver.adtech.de/adserv|3.0|258|1653713|0|170|ADTECH;loc=300;grp=[group]" border="0" width="300" height="250"></a></noscript>

    <!-- End of JavaScript Tag -->
```

You could see the url here: http://www.niceoutput.com/jquery/

Thanks in advance for your help

Mário

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, wouldn't

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //your code to execute when HTML is fully loaded
  });
```

work?

Comment: Wouldn't `jQuery(function () { })` be even better, conciseness-wise? :)

Comment: it didn't work, or maybe i'm doing something wrong.

If i put the inline javascript inside the $(document).ready how can i reference it to the div#himedia beacause i want the inline javascript to load it inside that div.

thanks for help

Comment: You can reference any element of the dom using jQuery selectors. For example $("div#himedia").html("YOUR HTML STRING");

Comment: Don't work, it's supposed to load the inline javascript not the html

Comment: Can you explain the use case for loading inline javascript this way? Can the same not be accomplished by calling a function when you are done loading the page?

Comment: What i want is to load the html first then load the div#himedia with the inline javascript, and i don't know how to do it.
I hope you understand it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // your code here

});
```

before writing any jquery codes..